# Mypy assign to Any error with --strict-optional

Tags: python, types, mypy

I have two functions. One returns a mix of stuff, so I've got its return type as `Dict[str, Any]`. This first function calls another function with a return type of `Dict[str, str]`. This result is included within the first function's return dict. This seems fine to me. Shouldn't this fit under `Any`? 
But mypy complains saying, `example.py:12: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Dict[str, str]", target has type "Union[Dict[<nothing>, <nothing>], bool, str, None]")`

You can test this minimal example as follows:
`$ mypy --strict-optional example.py`

```
from typing import Dict, Any


def function_one(variable: Dict[str, str]) -> Dict[str, Any]:
    result = {
        'this': None,
        'email': variable['eggs'],
        'allowed': False,
        'more_stuff': {}
    }
    response_two = function_two(variable)
    result['more_stuff'] = response_two
    return result


def function_two(stuff: Dict[str, str]) -> Dict[str, str]:
    result = {
        'one': stuff['spam']
    }
    return result
```

I don't get the error when I leave out the `--strict-optional` flag, but I'd like to leave it in, as according to the [docs](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_line.html#additional-command-line-flags), *"This flag will become the default in the near future."*

After reading through the docs a bit, I thought that changing `function_one`'s return type to `Dict[str, Optional[Any]]` would perhaps fix things, but I still get the same mypy error.

Comment: [mcve], please.

Comment: Question edited to add a working example.

Comment: It looks like mypy has inferred a too-strict type for `result`. Update mypy, consider filing a [report](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues) if it still does the same thing on the latest version, and for now, maybe put a variable annotation on `result`.